# Large activity on specific posts

Tags: discussion

I have always noticed that some topics(like limits and algebra precalculus) get a large attention and multiple people want to answer it. I know these topics are fascinating and have always liked the different answers that users post. However there are other topics which receive little attention.

I do understand that this has to do with complexity of the question and the knowledge level of the currently active stack users, but what can we do as a community to get rid of this disparity?

One idea is to encourage people with higher knowledge to give time to other users to answer simple questions.

Comment: The amount of people learning topics in linear algebra and pre-calculus is much, much larger than the amount of people learning about coherent sheaves or derived functors. Even in universities the ratio of students taking classes for the former topics to the latter may be in ratios of 10:1 or more. There's not much we can do about it. It seems your question is not about the disparity of posts but user with more knowledge answering those questions before letting other users do so. Can you edit your post to make this clear?

Comment: I feel that these are not two different issues. Knowledgeable users spending time on rather complex problems automatically means less disparity. But then again, this is just one solution the main problem(the disparity) and there could be a lot of different ways that could be done, which is exactly what I wish to be discussed under this post.

Comment: You can find some related discussions here on meta, such as: [Concern about lesser attention towards relatively advanced questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11936), [Proposal for promoting more interesting, deeper questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13472), [Best and worst tags for % answered rate](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/23148). Some users are trying to highlight quality content, including the more advanced topics: [Launching *Pearl Dive* - a chatroom where excellent questions/answers meet willing sponsors](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/31105).

Comment: I am not sure I think the disparity is a problem, and as a community we have never requested some users refrain from answering questions (as long as these follow the site's policy). It seems you are relatively new to the site, and this impression of "disparity" is usually something that happens to new users. I think there may even be duplicate posts asking about it. In fact, I asked a related question about 9 years ago [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3592/sponsoring-answers). Maybe it helps.